# Trying to fill input with object on create page

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I'm new to symfony and I'm trying to learn but I'm stuck at the moment :

I'm trying to create a form with input already filled, let me explain :

I've got a Session table, linked with an antibiotic (when I create a session, I choose an Antibiotic), Antibiotic table is linked to Result table.

Like this : [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKKyr.png)

What I'm trying to do, is when I click on Valid Result on Result list page, it creates a form of a new result with antibiotic input already filled (because a Session has one Antibiotic)

This is what i've got now (where 6 is the Antibiotic ID from the Session) :
[Add Results page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKiHt.png)

I've tried to look on how edit pages works with no results.

Thanks

```
 /**
 * @Route("/session/resultat/{id}", name="addResultat")
 */
    public function voirAction($id, Request $request){

        //Find the Session object
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $session=$em->getRepository("AppBundle:Session")
                ->find($id);
            if ($session==null)
                {
                    throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException("Ouste !");
                }
        $resultat = new Resultat();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ResultatType', $resultat);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($resultat);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('resultat_show', array('id' => $resultat->getId()));
        }
        return $this->render('resultat/addresultats.html.twig', array(
            'resultat' => $resultat,
            'session' => $session,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

I got it to work finally thanks to  ccKep :

Just set my object before creating the form like this :
So after I initialised my new "resultat", i can set his "antibiotique" with setter method and I get it from the $session with the getter method

```
$resultat->setAntibiotique($session->getAntibiotique());
```

Comment: please share your action code which is linked with the form

Comment: Just use `$resultat->setAntibiotique($session->getAntibiotique())` before your `createForm` call. (or, in other words: Just set the property of the new entity before creating the form).

Comment: my understanding is you want the `$session` data to get populated in form correct?

Comment: @ccKep Thanks, but I already tried that, doesn't seems to work :( and my getter and setter seems corrects too.

Comment: @Baig I want the $resultat to get populated with what $session have (like antibiotic for example)

Comment: have you tried this $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ResultatType', $session);

Comment: You might want to add your `ResultatType` form class and the mapping information regarding `Antibiotique` from `Resultat` and `Session` to your question.

Comment: @Baig I was trying to create a new Resultat, but ok i got it to work finaly with the ccKep method !

Comment: @ccKep I got it to work, I had a little problem with my setter for Antibiotique ! Thanks a lot !